# How to do Data binding in extjs 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

i have json like this.

```
     firstName: 'xyz',
     comments : [{
        emailAddress : "abc@gmail.com", body : "PQR",
        emailAddress : "xyz@gmail.com", body : "XYZ",
     }]
```

i want to show firstName in the textfield which is editable. and want to show comments in the grid. i am not able to understand how to do it. please help me with that.

my view is following:

```
    Ext.define("SampleView", {
       extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
       alias: 'widget.sample',
       id : 'sampleVId',
       requires: ['StudentViewModel'],
       viewModel: { 
            type: 'StudentViewModel' 
       },
       layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
       },

  initComponent: function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        items: [this.form(), this.grid()],           
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
 },

grid: function(){
    return {
        xtype: 'grid',
        reference: 'samplegrid',
        id : 'samplegridId',
        bind: {
            store: '{comment}'<-- not able to do the binding
        },
        flex:1,
        margin: 10,
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'rowediting',
            clicksToEdit: 2
        },
        columns: [{
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                allowBlank: false
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Role',
            dataIndex: 'body',
        }],
        }
    }
},


form : function(){
    return{
        xtype : 'form',
        items:[{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            bind: {
                value: '{firstName}'<---- how to bind this valuw to     textfield
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

});

my view model is like this:

```
    Ext.define('StudentViewModel', {
       extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
       alias:'viewmodel.StudentViewModel',
       requires: [
           'Student'
       ],

      stores: {
            orderStore: {
              autoLoad:true,
              type: 'sampleS'
            }
       }
    });
```

my model is like this:

```
    Ext.define('Student', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       idProperty: 'Id',
       schema: {
           namespace: 'sample',
           proxy: {
              type:'ajax',
              url: 'users.json',
              reader:{
                 type:'json',
                 rootProperty:'data'
             }
         }
     },
    fields: [
        { name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'firstName', type: 'string' },
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binding would have to be based on the record selected.

Your model for student needs to be defined to have a hasMany reference to a comments model so a proper store is built to be bound, or you would have to dynamically create a store based on the array data within the model. I would suggest just using a relation, its easier to do in the long run.

where you have the binding of

```
value: {firstName}
```

It should be

```
value: {student.firstName}
```

In your view controller you would have to bind student to the student model you are trying to display in the form using a line that looks like

```
vm.setValue('student', YOURMODELOBJECTHERE);
```

If the student model has a proper has many relation for comments, then the rest should be okay.